# Adding a height to polyline on mobile app map

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

I am developing a mapping app for iOS and Android in AS3/Air and wondering if there is a way to add a height to a polyline or polygon?

What I mean is when the map is in tilt mode show/add a height to the polylines similar to how buildings height are shown when the map is zoomed in.

I am using Distriqts Native Map extension.

Cheers!